# Open file with other editor with toolbar button - RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an **rcp** application with two editors (extending the Editorpart) in two different plugins, and i want create a toolbar-button to switch betwen **editor/plugins** with same file.

Is that possible?

regards
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, just get the active workbench page and call `IWorkbenchPage.openEditor(input, editorId)`.

Comment: how i can get all available editors of all plugins? 
Because i have two editors in two different plugins..

Comment: @AlexandrePinheiro From `IExtensionRegistry.getConfigurationElementsFor("org.eclipse.ui.editors");`, if you really want all of them, I think.

Comment: I put a new question [(here)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863111/workbenchpage-openeditor-does-nothing)  about this because I am not getting. 

thanks for your help it was essential to be able to do this! :)