# WorkbenchPage.openEditor() does nothing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying make a toolbar button to open one file with another editor on my **RCP aplication**!

I have de following code:

```
        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    IEditorPart oldEditor = page.getActiveEditor();
    IFile file = ((IFileEditorInput) oldEditor.getEditorInput()).getFile();

    IConfigurationElement[] editorsElements = Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getConfigurationElementsFor("org.eclipse.ui.editors");

    IEditorInput editorInput = new FileEditorInput(file);

    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page2 = window.getActivePage();
    try {
        page2.openEditor(editorInput, editorsElements[3].getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println("==>>"+editorInput+">>>>"+ editorsElements[3].getAttribute("id"));
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but when i call de action, he did not do anything! but also does not return error..

The result of `System.out.println()` looks like correct:

**==>>org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput(/g/Network.int)>>>>DesignEditor**

what i do wrong?

I following  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846147/open-file-with-other-editor-with-toolbar-button-rcp/) advice to do my button

Sorry my english 
Regards

Answer (score 1):

The id value should be more like a java package name: org.myorg.tooling.designeditor

Comment: so just to clarify: You should have a single-token id defined in you plugin.xml (e.g. "designeditor") and your plugin.xml and/or manifest.MF should declare a plugin-id for your plugin (e.g. "org.myorg.tooling") and the editor id you specify in the API call is the concatenation of the two (with a period in there).  right?

Comment: right! my editor id is "**DesignEditor**", and my plugin id is "**IntergridPlugin.integridPlugin**", when i call, i call "**IntergridPlugin.integridPlugin.DesignEditor**.

Comment: I tried with `page2.openEditor(editorInput,"org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor");`, and it's the same.